# Python no inserta registro en Mysql

Tags: mysql, python

Tengo un script en `Python` bastante sencillo, dónde inserto un registro en Mysql, pero por alguna razón, no se está insertando, y no me da error alguno, ya que ejecuta el **print(sql)**

Es raro, porque si cambio la sentencia por **TRUNCATE TEMPERATURE** funciona perfecto y trunca la tabla

```html
class DataBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            password='',
            db='home'
        )

        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    
    def insert_temperature(self, date, temperature, humidity):
        sql = "INSERT INTO TEMPERATURE (DATE, TEMPERATURE, HUMIDITY) VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}')".format(now, temperature_c, humidity)
        
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            print(sql)

        except Exception as e:
            raise

dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT11(board.D2)
temperature_c = dhtDevice.temperature
humidity = dhtDevice.humidity
now = '2020-12-18'

database = DataBase()
database.insert_temperature(now, temperature_c, humidity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado, me faltaba añadir **commit()**

```
self.cursor.execute(sql)
self.connection.commit()
```